# Хочу сделать ограничение бота в беседах ВКонтакте. Питон

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Авторизируюсь через пользователя. Хочу сделать так, что если пишешь в беседе, к примеру, с идентификатором 1, то работало все, но если в беседе 2, то ничего не писалось. Делаю ограничение через peer_id, питон ругается на reply, хотя он мне нужен. Спасибо за решение проблемы.
Сам код:

````
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vk_api
import requests
from vk_api.longpoll import *
from vk_api.utils import *
from vk_api.keyboard import *

token = "фу"

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="бе", api_version='5.89')
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi (token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll (vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api ()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        if event.text == "Sitis баф атаки" or event.text == "sitis баф атаки" or event.text == "ситис баф атаки"  or event.text == "Ситис баф атаки" :
            if event.from_chat:
                vk.messages.send(
                chat_id=event.chat_id,
                random_id=get_random_id(),

                message='Благословение атаки',
                reply_to=event.message_id
        )
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтоб узнать чат-айди сообщения, необходимо ввести строку message = chat_id
Покажется айди чата, который можно впихнуть в chat_id.